# Problems with PostGIS CTE

Tags: postgis

I am trying to run the `with-as` example on slide 22 from
http://www.postgis.us/downloads/oscon2009_PostGISTips.pdf

When I paste the example in the SQL-shell I get the following error:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: record - integer LINE 14: ... x, y,
>   ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2d(ST_Point(xmin + (x - 1)*g_wid...
>   HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add 
>   explicit type casts

I  am using `POSTGIS 1.4.1` with `Postgres 8.4`
I used the data that accompany the slides
http://www.bostongis.com/downloads/oscon2009/oscon2009_src.zip

I also tried the states data from the web with:

```
shp2pgsql -s  2163  statesp020.shp public.states  > states.sql
psql -U postgres -d postgis -f states.sql
```

But got same error.
Any advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error "record - integer" (`x - 1`) can be fixed by giving the result from `generate_series` the intended aliases `x` and `y`. Find this part:

```
...
(SELECT generate_series(1,x_gridcnt) FROM usext) As x CROSS JOIN
(SELECT generate_series(1,y_gridcnt) FROM usext) As y CROSS JOIN
...
```

where the `x` and `y` values were actually called `x.generate_series` and `y.generate_series`.

Change this to:

```
...
(SELECT generate_series(1,x_gridcnt) As x FROM usext) As x CROSS JOIN
(SELECT generate_series(1,y_gridcnt) As y FROM usext) As y CROSS JOIN
...
```

where they are now called `x.x` and `y.y`, or implied as just `x` and `y`.